# Tensorflow add new op slicing the output tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I checked the file [here](https://github.com/taxfromdk/tensorflow_dense_op/blob/master/dense.cc#L109):

```
// get the corresponding Eigen tensors for data access
auto input_tensor = input.matrix<double>();
auto weights_tensor = weights.matrix<double>();
auto biases_tensor = biases.matrix<double>();
auto output_tensor = output->matrix<double>();

for (int ix_sample = 0; ix_sample < batch_samples; ix_sample++) {
  for (int ix_unit = 0; ix_unit < units; ix_unit++) {
    output_tensor(ix_sample, ix_unit) = 0;
    for (int ix_input = 0; ix_input < input_feature_width; ix_input++) {
      output_tensor(ix_sample, ix_unit) += input_tensor(ix_sample, ix_input) * weights_tensor(ix_input, ix_unit );
    }  
    output_tensor(ix_sample, ix_unit) += biases_tensor(0, ix_unit);
  }
}
```

And the one on [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op):

```
// Create an output tensor
Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                 &output_tensor));
auto output_flat = output_tensor->flat<int32>();

// Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
const int N = input.size();
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
  output_flat(i) = 0;
}
```

I am wondering if the output tensor is a 3d tensor, how could I slice it and assign its value vector-wise.

I find the `slice` method for `Eigen`:

```
Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> a(4, 3);
a.setValues({{0, 100, 200}, {300, 400, 500},
             {600, 700, 800}, {900, 1000, 1100}});
Eigen::array<int, 2> offsets = {1, 0};
Eigen::array<int, 2> extents = {2, 2};
Eigen::Tensor<int, 1> slice = a.slice(offsets, extents);
cout << "a" << endl << a << endl;
=>
a
   0   100   200
 300   400   500
 600   700   800
 900  1000  1100
cout << "slice" << endl << slice << endl;
=>
slice
 300   400
 600   700
```

But not clear how could I use it here.